# Why JSONResult converts Camel case property names to Lowercase?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

**Project Overview**

I'm working on a project which is based on:

1- Angular 6

2- Aspnet Core 2.1

**Scenario**

I'm calling a get request using below code in angular

```
let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  this.http.get(this._URL).subscribe(
    (data => {
      this._engineersList = data[0];
      this._shiftList = data[1];
      console.log(data[0])
    }), error => this.error
  );

class Engineers {
    public ID: number;
    public Name: string;
}

class Shifts {
    public ID: number;
    public EmployeeID: number;
    public EmployeeName: string;
    public ShiftName: string;
    public ShiftTime: string;
}
```

As my properties names are in Camel case. Obviously, I bind same as in my HTML like below:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let engineer of _engineersList">
      <td>
        {{engineer.Id}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{engineer.Name}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I'm getting below output (No data bind):

[image]

But when I convert my Camel case properties in lower case like:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let engineer of _engineersList">
      <td>
        {{engineer.id}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{engineer.name}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

[image]

**Findings**

When I check returning result of my GET request in browser console I found that my observable returning properties in lowercase.

[image]

Also, I verify this on server side but there is no such issue were found. Server returning me the correct data with properly in Camel case.

[image]

What I'm trying to say is why my JSON Result is showing and binding my properties name in lowercase? As you can see on the top of this post I've created a model class and their properties are in Camel Case they should bind as it is on my HTML but its not working. Please help me on this what I'm doing wrong in my code. Hope I briefly explain my question.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297396/how-to-preserve-object-property-casing-when-using-rxjs-map-function and https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4842

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I'm searching.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core you can add this to Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing around with the middleware properties?
You might be looking to force Camel or Pascal Case here?

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;
}
```